# Object is cut in "3D View"

Tags: 3d-view

This is a 3D view of a 2m x 2m x 2m cube, created by scaling up a standard cube from the grid center. The grey plane are the gridlines. It looks as if the 3D View camera can't pull backward enough. What's wrong? [image]

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you clipping value is very low. To fix it press the ‘N’ key to open the property bar. In that there is something called ‘clip’ and under that there is start and end values. Increase the end value for something like 10m or 100m. If I am right (99.99%) this solution should work. Thank you